# Drush: Permission denied outside htdocs

Tags: drush, files

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours now.

I successfully installed Drush locally and it works fine when I'm using it within XAMPP's htdocs folder. However, I want to move the Drupal folder to a virtual host outside htdocs. When I run drush inside the new folder, it says:

```
$ drush status

PHP Warning:  pcntl_exec(): Error has occurred: (errno 13) Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc on line 359

Warning: pcntl_exec(): Error has occurred: (errno 13) Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc on line 359
Error has occurred executing the Drush script found at /Users/ivan/drush
(errno 13) Permission denied
```

Tried to change folder owner to admin group, chmod -R 777 - nothing worked. I am running on OS X 10.11.6 and XAMPP 5.6.12.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have two Drush installations - `/Users/ivan/drush` and `/usr/local/bin/drush` I'm guessing that `/Users/ivan/drush` isn't executable and hence causing the error. I suggest just removing `/Users/ivan/drush`.

Comment: What a stupid mistake. This totally solved my problem, thanks!